# Why does $.load( handler(eventObject) ) not work for data returned from server after Ajax request, trying to make it wait for all images to load

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I need to keep displaying the loading gif until all images
in the returned data (html) have been finished loading.
The data and everything is returned properly, but the .live('load', function() {})
is never executed, have tried without the .live as well. The contents of #ContentBody
just get replaced with the returned html data (#LoadingLayer disappears too of course) and I can see images loading as usual.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $("#RightLink").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var tourl = $(this).attr('data-ajax-url');


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: tourl,
            dataType: "html",

            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#LoadingLayer").show(); //show layer with image loading gif
                $('#ColumnContainer').hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {

                $('#ContentBody').html(data).live('load', function () { $("#LoadingLayer").hide(); });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

HTML layout:

```
<body>

    <div id="ContentBody">

    <a id="RightLink" href="/store/ContentBodyGenerator" />

    <div id="LoadingLayer"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>

    <div id="ColumnContainer">... Main contents, lots of images here</div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: HTML loaded and image loaded are 2 different events.  You need to handle the image loaded events separately.

Comment: Why use live when you already have the html?  Also, the load handler will get called after the first matched element triggers it, and your #LoadingLayer will get hidden.

Comment: @Archer Then any good example out there of a script that will not display/insert the returned data until everything in it, including images have been loaded? I just want the fully loaded page to come on and loading gif to disappear then.

Comment: @Madbreaks Actually it does not run the .load at all in this scenario. At least putting debugger; or alert('something'); in the function(){} inside the .load does nothing.

Comment: Added an answer, the issue I think is that you're not binding to the load event to the images.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just hide `#LoadingLayer` directly?

```
$('#ContentBody').html(data);
$("#LoadingLayer").hide();
```

Edit:

I misread your question, I don't think there is an easy way to detect that all images have been loaded. I suggest you try the [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) plugin.

Comment: How will that help with displaying loading gif until all images in returned data(html) have been loaded. I want spining gif displayed until all images are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the contents of the "success" function to this...

```
$('#ContentBody').html(data).live('load', function () {
    var imgcount = $(this).find("img").length;
    $(this).find("img").one("load", function() {
        imgcount--;
        if (imgcount == 0) {
            $("#LoadingLayer").hide();
        }
    }).each(function() {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
});
```

It waits till html(data) is loaded and then gets an image count.  It then adds an event handler to each of the images to decrement the image count when the image is loaded.  The `one("load"` code means only allows the following code to run once, and the `each` code basically says "if it's already loaded (as per cached images) then run the load event".

Once the image count is 0 it hides the loading layer.

Without a URL where I can run this through the console I can't be 100% sure it's accurate, so it may need a fiddle about.  If you get stuck give us a shout.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the load event to the images.  Keep track of how many have loaded, and remove the loading layer only after they've all loaded.  This is untested code but should give you an idea:

```
success:function(data){
    // Set the content
    $('#ContentBody').html(data);

    // How many images do we have?
    var images = $('#ContentBody img'),
        leftToLoad = images.size();

    // Listen for load event *FOR IMAGES*
    images.bind('load', function (){
        // Hey look we loaded one, was that the last one?
        if(--leftToLoad === 0){
            // Yep, we're done
            $("#LoadingLayer").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

If you'd rather use live than handling in the ajax callback, do this in your $(document).ready callback:

```
$('#ContentBody img').live('load', function(){...});
```

Should do the trick.

Cheers